# How to have a coroutine wait on serial input?

Tags: serial-port, python-asyncio

I have a structure similar to what described in [Equivalent of asyncio.Queues with worker "threads"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864341/equivalent-of-asyncio-queues-with-worker-threads).

Difference is my "producer" will open a serial line and asynchronously parse input till a "token" is recognized (instead of generating random numbers). Tokens are then passed via asyncio.Queue to "consumer".

Tentative code includes:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def produce():
    with open('infile.cmd', 'r') as ifd:
        while True:
            cmd = yield from ifd.readline()
            if cmd is None:
                break
            print("received {}".format(cmd))
            yield from q.put(cmd)
```

but this doesn't work because of "RuntimeError: Task got bad yield: 'p'" on the `ifd.readline()` line.

I also tried using a `Reader` (cfr.: [Using asyncio to read the output of a serial port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793812/using-asyncio-to-read-the-output-of-a-serial-port)):

```
event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    with open('infile.cmd', 'r') as ifd:
        event_loop.add_reader(ifd, produce)
    event_loop.create_task(consume())
    print('entering event loop')
    event_loop.run_forever()
```

but this bombs with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mcon/trasmissione-telematica/Communications/prove/asio.py", line 32, in <module>
    event_loop.add_reader(ifd, produce)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 337, in add_reader
    return self._add_reader(fd, callback, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 267, in _add_reader
    (handle, None))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/selectors.py", line 412, in register
    self._epoll.register(key.fd, epoll_events)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

How can I asynchronously read from something?

*Note:* in this example I'm reading from file, but in the end I'll have to read binary data from a non-blocking serial line (either /dev/ttySx or named pipe), so o line-oriented input will be allowed; data must be read as soon as it's available and "producer" is responsible to understand when a "cmd" is complete.

Comment: Check out aioserial: https://github.com/changyuheng/aioserial

Answer (score 0):

Using [aiofiles](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aiofiles) and python 3.5+ the following code worked great:

```
async def produce():
    async with aiofiles.open('test.cmd', mode = 'r') as ifd:
        while True:
            cmd = await ifd.readline()
            #readlines ourput is not stripped
            cmd = cmd.strip()
            if not cmd or cmd=='stop':
                print("finished")
                break
            print("cmd {}".format(cmd))
            await q.put(cmd)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
q = asyncio.Queue()
loop.run_until_complete(produce())
```

test.cmd

```
mv hello
cp world
stop
```

output:

```
cmd mv hello
cmd cp world
finished
```